# postfix (prefix) increment, L-value and R-value (in C and C++)

Tags: c++, c, operators, operand, operands

I just learned the following facts:

> - The result of a prefix increment (++var_name) is an R-value in C (at least, I am
>       sure that it is not a L-value in C), but it is an L-value in C++.
> - The result of a postfix increment (var_name++) is an R-value in C (at least, I am
>       sure that it is not a L-value in C). This is also true in C++ (It says the result
>       is a prvalue).

I checked these in VS2010 (.cpp and .c) and Ubuntu (gcc and g++).

In p.109 (5.3.2) of C++ Standard http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf, it is written

> *The operand of prefix ++ is modified by adding 1, or set to true if it is bool (this use is deprecated). The
>   operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a pointer to
>   a completely-defined object type. **The result is the updated operand; it is an lvalue**, and...*

and in p.101, (5.2.6)

> The value of a postfix ++ expression is the value of its operand. ... **The result is a
>   prvalue**. The type of the result is the cv-unqualified version of the type of the operand. See also 5.7 and 5.17.

(I don't know the difference between R-value and prvalue though).

As to C standard http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf,
prefix ++ is described in 6.5.3.1 and postfix is in 6.5.2.4, but from the description, I can't get a clear, definite answer.

I would like to know the reasons that make them being R-value or L-value. All I know is that

`We can assign a value to a (modifiable) L-value, for example, a variable name. R-value is a value of an expression.`

**But I don't know the details why postfix ++ is not a L-value in C and C++, and why prefix ++ is not in C.** (I saw something like "postfix ++...store...in a temporary address, then...", but I still don't get it).

And another question is that why prefix ++ is different in C and C++? Making prefix ++ a L-value (in C++) has many advantages? If so, why C doesn't change this? (Other reasons than backward compatibility, or at least why changing it will cause a lot of problems).

Comment: You said you checked your assumptions in VS2010 and gcc. What code did you use to verify your assumptions about these issues?

Comment: ""(I saw something like "postfix ++...store...in a temporary address, then...", but I still don't get it)"" - Maybe if you quote the whole sentence from the standard that you don't get, someone could clarify it for you.

Comment: @Brandin, it is not in the standard. I saw it on a book, which says "The expression   a++   in the third statement is an rvalue because it stores the value of   a   
temporarily as the result of the expression and then increments   a  . "

Comment: Also, just using statements like `(a++) = 3`, `(++a) = 3`.

Comment: Do those examples produce different results on different C and C++ compilers? I thought your question was about a difference between C and C++.

Comment: No, the results are just the same as described the standards, in each compiler I tried. My question is about difference between C and C++ as you said, not the compiler.

Comment: That standard (N3242) is pretty old.

Comment: It is in 2011. It's old?

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ are different languages.  C++ has operator overloading and C does not.  The **++** operators, whether prefix or postfix, are operators which can be overloaded in C++.  C++ also has references and C does not.

In C, **++i** and **i++** both yield a value which is not an *lvalue*.  This is desirable, as otherwise you could run afoul with undefined behaviour by trying to modify the same scalar within the same sequence-point boundaries.

Food for thought: In C, the comma operator also produces a value which is not an lvalue, so to "drop" *lvalueness*, you can do:

```
(0, lvalue)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is true that

- pre increment/decrement operator (++var or --var) yields an lvalue (i.e a modifiable object)
- post increment/decrement operator (var++ or var--) yields an rvalue (i.e a temporary object).

Consider following code with pre increment/decrement operator

```
{

int i = 0;

int* pi = &(++i);

}
```

It´s OK because in fact its pseudo code is

```
i = i+1; // pre increment i

int* pi = &i; // then evaluate its address and assign it to pi
```

Now consider the same code but with post increment/decrement operator and the consequences if this invalid code is accepted by the compiler

```
{

int i = 0;

int* pi = &(i++); // Not OK !! because it is a temporary variable

}
```

Its pseudo code would be

```
int i = 0;

int tmp = i; // compiler creates a temporary variable to save value of i

int* pi = &tmp; // then would take the address of a temporary variable 

i = i + 1;
```