# Increment operator on reference variable

Tags: c++

Why does pre-increment work but post-increment does not on a reference variable?

```
#include <iostream>

void swap(int&, int&);

int main()
{
    int x=10, y=20;
    int &a=x, &b=y;
    swap(++a, ++b);  //swap (a++,b++) is not allowed.
    printf("%d %d ", a, b);
    return 0;
}

void swap(int& x, int& y)
{
    x+=2;
    y+=3;
}
```

Why is `swap(++a, ++b)` allowed but `swap(a++, b++)` says:

> [Error] invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'

Comment: For simplicity's sake, note that the same behaviour occurs if you try to use `main`'s `x` and `y` directly. References `a` and `b` only serve to make the problem appear more complicated than it is.

Answer (score 14):

When you call

```
swap (a++,b++)
```

`a++` and `b++` give you a temporary object since post incrementing returns the previous values.  Since `swap()` takes its parameters by reference they cannot bind to those temporary values.  using `++a` and `++b` work as we first increment `a` and `b` and then pass it to swap so there is no temporary.

Answer (score 2):

++a returns an l-value but a++ returns an r-value. You need to pass an l-value to the swap() function.

Relevant post on l-valu and r-value: [postfix (prefix) increment, L-value and R-value (in C and C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351799/postfix-prefix-increment-l-value-and-r-value-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 2):

The function `std::swap` must swap the value of two variable, aka a lvalue reference. The expression `x++` is not a variable, but a value, or a rvalue. A rvalue cannot be bound to a lvalue reference.

The difference between a rvalue and a lvalue could be explained that way:

```
int p;
/* p is left value, 3 is right value, ok */
p = 3;
```

But the following is not valid:

```
/* not ok, 3 is right value */
3 = p;
```

What you are sending to  `std::swap` are two value of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

**Passing l-value / variable:**

```
int x = 5, y = 9;
swap(x, y); // allowed bcos x and y are l-values / variables
```

pre-increment (also **pre-decrement**):

```
int x = 5, y = 9;
swap(++x, ++y); // allowed bcos ++x and ++y are l-values
```

**Passing r-value / value:**

```
swap(5, 9); // NOT allowed bcos 5 and 9 are values (NOT variables)
```

post-increment (also **post-decrement**):

```
int x = 5, y = 9;
swap(x++, y++); // NOT allowed bcos x++ and y++ are r-values
```