# Equivalent code in C for the following call by reference in c++

Tags: c++, c, recursion, pass-by-reference

What will be the equivalent code in C for the following C++ code?

```
int main()  
{  
    //... 
    int count=0;  
    fun(++count);  //function call
    //... 
}  
void fun(int &count)  //function definition
{  
    //...  
    fun(++count);  //Recursive Function call
    //... 
}
```

Here `count` variable is used to keep a track on number of calls of `fun()`

Comment: I don't think post-increment works with reference parameters.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911353/increment-operator-on-reference-variable

Comment: cannot say equivalent, but you can use either `static` variable or a pointer to get the same behavior in `C`

Comment: My C++ is rusty. How can you pass an expression by reference? Why would you want to increment `count` once when calling and once in the function if the purpose is to count function calls?

Comment: @Mat I am sorry; my code will be `++count`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use pointer:

```
int main()
{  
    int count = 0;
    ++count;
    fun(&count);  //function call
    // ...
}

void fun(int *count)  //function definition
{
    // ...

    ++*count;
    fun(count);  //Recursive Function call
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I already moved incrementation before the call, instead of after.